# Proof without numbering

Tags: numbering, amsthm, proof-package

I am trying to remove the number from proof, but I could not. When I used `amsthm` package I got several errors. How to remove numbering of proofs without using `amsthm` package?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}                         
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\def\NoNumber#1{{\def\alglinenumber##1{}\State #1}\addtocounter{ALG@line}{-1}}
%\usepackage{mymacro}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Corollary}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{pro}[thm]{Proof}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
A
\end{thm}

\begin{pro}
B
\end{pro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use the  `ntheorem` package, which defines an `unnumbered` theorem style. But probably you should post a minimal (yet complete) code reproducing your problem.

Comment: How to use `ntheorem` package?

Comment: With `\usepackage` in the preamble. However, I'm very surprised that `amsthm` numbers proofs. There must be something in your preamble that induces this behaviour.

Comment: I used it, but got errors.

Comment: Please post a full minimal code, that we can play with.

Comment: Amsthm comes with a proof env, in ntheorem you have to make the proof environment yourself using a suitable theorem style. Both packages have manuals you can consult.

Comment: I have posted the code.

Comment: Please cite these errors. Note that your exampleis using stuff one should not use like epsfig and amsfonts (the latter is autoloaded by amssymb) but you load neither ntheorem or amsthm

Comment: @Bernard amsthm does not number proofs, this seems to be a fixture of trying to use ntheorem setup with amsthm

Comment: @daleif: I don't think so. The O.P. didn't know the existence of ntheorem.

Comment: Finally, it works. I removed epsfig and amsfonts  and then used amsthm. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Bernard if the op had just googled it and copied the code without realising they needed to load ntheorem for that. There was a problem with wiki books at one point with their stuff about algorithms, it was not at all clear which packages was needed for the example code they gave (it was just sniplets not proper mwes)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Perhaps I'm blind, but the code doesn't show any `\usepackage{amsthm}`, so the question doesn't make any sense.  As already noted, the `amsthm` environment `proof` doesn't number anything.  This question should thus be a candidate for deletion.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?
[image]
The following tex file was modified from yours at those three commented lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}                              % <---- added this line
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}                         
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,microtype}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\def\NoNumber#1{{\def\alglinenumber##1{}\State #1}\addtocounter{ALG@line}{-1}}
%\usepackage{mymacro}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Corollary}[thm]{Corollary}
%\newtheorem{pro}[thm]{Proof}                    % <--- commented out this line
\newenvironment{pro}{\begin{proof}}{\end{proof}} % <-- added this line
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
A
\end{thm}

\begin{pro}
B
\end{pro}

\end{document}
```